# How to apologize to your boss and ask for one more day of vacation

Tags: phrase-usage

Yesterday I asked for leave on 14 and 15 day, but I was wrong and I need another 16 day.
How to apologize and ask for more vacation?

Comment: ELL is not a "write it for me" site. If you have any questions about the grammaticality of a sentence, or how native speakers would write the same sentences, that would be a better question, provided that you explain why you think the sentence you write is wrong.

Comment: "Sorry, boss, can we add an extra day? I need to take the 16th off, too."

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason for closure may be a bit fuzzy: this could have been closed for being too broad, or because it was "unclear of what you're asking," or because it is primarily opinion-based. Fact is, there are countless ways to "apologize and ask for more vacation," including, _"I'd like to apologize and ask for more vacation,"_ and that's why this question was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasing you've already used in your question would be good enough. The only real error I can spot would be that "14 and 15 day" would be referred to as "the 14th and 15th". You should also mention the month if it's not already clear which month you're referring to.

> I know I asked yesterday for the 14th and 15th off work and I'm really sorry but I made a mistake and I need the 16th off too. Could I please take that day off as well?